# Why is cap_net_bind_service not working in this nginx nested Docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, linux-capabilities, kind

The [nginx ingress controller](https://quay.io/repository/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller?tag=latest&tab=tags) for Kubernetes uses the cap_net_bind_service capability, which is a Linux filesystem attribute, to obtain the permissions to open a privileged port (port 80). However, I have a kind test which creates a local Kubernetes cluster using docker containers as virtual nodes (docker inside docker) and starts up an nginx ingress controller pod. This controller pod works fine in Docker Desktop on Windows 10, but when I run the same test on Linux, the controller pod repeatedly crashes on startup, with:

```
[17:27:34]nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Yet the required capability exists in the nested Docker container:

```
$ allpods=$(kubectl get pods)
$ ingresspod=$(echo "$allpods"|grep '^nginx-ingress-controller'|head -n1)
$ kubectl exec "${ingresspod%% *}" -- getcap -v /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx = cap_net_bind_service+ep
```

SELinux is enabled but in permissive mode on the Linux host.

Comment: `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` is also a kernel permission that the user must be granted (or be root). You should see this in the `securityContext` of the `nginx-ingress` deploy. It's possible a pod security policy could stop that, but you don't get a psp by default with kind. I'm guessing the parent kind container or more likely the host is stopping it. What distro is the linux test running on?

Comment: SELinux would have been the first suggestion :)

Comment: Also what deployment are you using for the ingress controller?

Comment: @Matt Host distro is Oracle Linux 7.7. I'm not sure the securityContext is relevant, since SELinux is in permissive mode. Deployment is done with the official helm chart.

Comment: Ah, turns out the host doesn't have ambient capabilities available for some reason. `cat /proc/self/status|fgrep CapAmb` returns nothing, whereas on the container running on Docker Desktop on Windows, CapAmb shows up.

Comment: The securityContext is applied by the container runtime.  selinux/apparmor are a separate layer of security

Comment: Ah, SELinux also has a concept of security context - I got confused. OK, the capability is not set in the deployment in either case. I guess on Docker Desktop, the ambient capabilities kernel feature means that the capability gets passed through automatically. I'll try setting the capability in the deployment and see what happens.

Comment: Adding a securityContext to the helm chart didn't help.

Comment: Some part of docker requires sudo permission. Are you running docker as sudo ? Will be great if you share you script to reproduce the same scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be because on the Linux host, `dockerd` was being run with the `--no-new-privileges` option.